# Unable to retrieve value using //td[text()=" Ref. :"] in XPATH

Tags: java, xpath, nsxmlparser

```
  <TD colSpan=4> Ref. : XYZ</TD>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value XYZ using XPATH

```
  //td[text()=" Ref. :"]
```

But i am unable to get that ... can anyone find the error ..

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problems with your XPath expression and for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
substring-after(//TD[starts-with(text(),' Ref. :')]/text(),' Ref. : ')
```

That yields

```
XYZ
```

**Update**

Following Alejandro's remark about listing several nodes, here is a Java example of listing several TDs in Java (standard JDK Java parser).

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class TestXPath {

    private static final String FILE = "a.xhtml" ;
    private static final String XPATH = "//td[starts-with(.,'Ref. :')]";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(FILE);
            XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(XPATH);
            Object hits = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET ) ;
            if ( hits instanceof NodeList ) {
                NodeList list = (NodeList) hits ;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ ) {
                    System.out.println( list.item(i).getTextContent().substring( " Ref. :".length() ) );
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Applied to the following test xhtml file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>col1</td>
                <td>col2</td>
                <td>col3</td>
                <td>col4</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="4">Ref. : Line 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="4">Ref. : Line 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="4">Ref. : Line 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="4">Ref. : Line 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It yields

```
 Line 1
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
```

Comment: Don't use text nodes in a mixed content data model as XHTML, elements' string value is a better choice.

Comment: @Alejandro, Like this ? `substring-after(string(//TD[starts-with(.,' Ref. :')]),' Ref. : ')` or even `substring-after(string(//TD[starts-with(string(.),' Ref. :')]),' Ref. : ')` ?

Comment: Yes, something like `substring-after(//TD[starts-with(.,' Ref. :')],' Ref. : ')`. But do note that implicit casting would take only first selected `TD`.

Answer (score 1):

you can select whole text and then substring it in XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="normalize-space(substring-after(.//html:td/text(), 'Ref. :'))"/>
```

Comment: @Praneel So then select whole text value and then make substring in Java. I don't think that you can't work with value of nodes in XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

> `<TD colSpan=4> Ref. : XYZ</TD>`
>
> I am trying to retrieve the value XYZ
>   using XPATH
>
> `//td[text()=" Ref. :"]`
>
> But i am unable to get that ... can
>   anyone find the error ..

**Before anything else, one major problem of your XPath expression**:

```
  //td[text()=" Ref. :"]
```

being applied on the provided XML document:

```
  <TD colSpan=4> Ref. : XYZ</TD>
```

**is that XPath is case sensitive**.

Even if everything else is right (which it isn't), an expression using lower-case names will never select any node when applied on an XML document containing upper-cased names.

So, if we correct this problem the XPath expression becomes:

```
  //TD[text()=" Ref. :"]
```

While this expression will select the top (and only) element of the provided XML document, it doesn't produce the wanted value.

**The XPath I would use is**:

```
substring-after(/TD, 'Ref. : ')
```

or (knowing that a well-formed XML document has only one top element):

```
substring-after(/*, 'Ref. : ')
```